# invalid property 'ERROR_INTEGRATION' for 'TASK' message when defining TASK Object

Tags: amazon-web-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am  Receiving the following error

> invalid property 'ERROR_INTEGRATION' for 'TASK'

when adding notification integration property to TASK OBJECT in snowflake hosted on AWS.
I have defined notification integration <my_notifcation_int>  successfully.

invalid property 'ERROR_INTEGRATION' for 'TASK'

The definition of task is as follows :

```
  create task mytask
  schedule = '5 MINUTE'
  error_integration = <my_notification_int>
  as
  insert into mytable(ts) values(current_timestamp);
```

As per snowflake documentation, ERROR_INTEGRATION in TASK OBJECTS is supported.
Any suggestions on resolving this error?

Comment: Where in the documentation does it say this is supported? https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-task.html

Comment: @NickW [Enabling Error Notifications for Tasks](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tasks-errors.html#enabling-error-notifications-for-tasks)

Comment: As this is a preview feature I would suggest contacting Snowflake Support or your Snowflake Account Manager

Comment: Also, is your Snowflake account on AWS?

Comment: @MikeWalton Yes its hosted on AWS.